# perl script to read content between marks

Tags: regex, perl

In the perl , how to read the contents between two marks. Source data like this

```
START_HEAD
ddd
END_HEAD

START_DATA
eee|234|ebf
qqq|              |ff
END_DATA

--Generate at 2011:23:34
```

then I only want to get data between "START_DATA" and "END_DATA". How to do this ?

```
sub readFile(){ 
    open(FILE, "<datasource.txt") or die "file is not found";

    while(<FILE>){      
        if(/START_DATA/){           
            record(\*FILE);#start record;
        }
    }
}

sub record($){
    my $fileHandle = $_[0];

    while(<fileHandle>){
        print $_."\n";      
        if(/END_DATA/) return ;         
    }
}
```

I write this code, it doesn't work. do you know why ?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: For future reference, "doesn't work" is not very informative. You should include error messages, or other information about how it is not working.

Comment: `while <FILE> { print if /START_DATA/ .. /END_DATA/ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides a few typos, your code is not too far off. Had you used

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You might have figured it out yourself. Here's what I found:

- Don't use prototypes if you do not need them, or know what they do.

Normal sub declaration is `sub my_function (prototype) {`, but you can leave out the prototype and just use `sub my_function {`.

- `while (<fileHandle>) {` is missing the `$` sign to denote that it is
  a variable (scalar) and not a global. Should be `$fileHandle`.
- `print $_."\n";` will add an extra newline. Just `print;` will do
  what you expect.
- `if(/END_DATA/) return;` is a syntax error. Brackets are not optional
  in perl in this case. Unless you reverse the statement.

Use either:

```
return if (/END_DATA/);
```

or

```
if (/END_DATA/) { return }
```

Below is the cleaned up version. I commented out your `open()` while testing, so this would be a functional code example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

readFile();

sub readFile { 
    #open(FILE, "<datasource.txt") or die "file is not found";
    while(<DATA>) {      
        if(/START_DATA/) {
            recordx(\*DATA); #start record;
        }
    }
}

sub recordx {
    my $fileHandle = $_[0];
    while(<$fileHandle>) {
        print;
        if (/END_DATA/) { return }         
    }
}

__DATA__
START_HEAD
ddd
END_HEAD

START_DATA
eee|234|ebf
qqq|              |ff
END_DATA

--Generate at 2011:23:34
```

Comment: it still will print "END_DATA" , how to get rid of this ? thanks

Comment: @user595234 You can put the `return` statement before the print.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the range operator:

```
perl -ne 'print if /START_DATA/ .. /END_DATA/'
```

The output will include the *_DATA lines, too, but it should not be so hard to get rid of them.

Comment: Except, in scalar context (like this) it's not the range operator, it's the flip-flop operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple thing to do with regular expressions, just use the /s or /m (single line or multiple line) flags - /s allows the `.` operator to match newlines, so you can do `/start_data(.+)end_data/is`.

Comment: data is inside a file, how to do it ?